# How can I suppress g++ deprecation warnings in OCaml compilation when linking with C++ libraries?

Tags: c++, gcc, build, ocaml, gcc-warning

When compiling an OCaml project which links against libraries requiring the C++ standard library (e.g. LLVM's OCaml bindings) using the `-cc g++` argument to `ocamlc` with GCC >= 4.4 generates extremely verbose warning spew of the form:

```
warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
```

How is it possible to remove these warnings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem stems from `ocamlc` generating intermediate C code which triggers warnings when compiled in C++ mode by newer versions of GCC. But this generated code need not be compiled as C++. The only reason to pass `-cc g++` for this common case of building against a wrapped C++ library is to ensure that the C++ standard library dependencies are built. The simpler solution, which avoids using the C++ front-end for compiling the `ocamlc` intermediate code, is simply:

```
-cclib -lstdc++
```

which forces linking the generated C code with `libstdc++`, while still compiling it in plain C mode.

Comment: afaik it is better to compile ocamlc code with c compiler and use '-cc g++' when linking (-lstdc++ may not be sufficient)

Comment: Fair point, though this does work in all the environments I've tried. (g++ is generally just a wrapper which configures the GCC toolchain environment to do things like -lstdc++.) Any idea how to force -cc g++ to only be passed as a linker argument when using OCamlBuild?

Comment: `flag ["ocaml";"link";"native"] & atomize ["-cc";"g++"]` should work

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just do

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wwrite-strings"
```

In the C++ to suppress this.

Comment: This sidesteps the underlying problem rather than solving it. The deeper issue was OCaml's standard library using C which was not friendly to C++. The sources in question are not owned by the user, but by the underlying system, so modifying them all to add warning suppression pragmas is impractical.